# I think cetasikas are programmed submind?

Tags: abhidhamma

So far I was under impression that cetasicas are elementary  mental factor. but I did not pay attention to all 52 of them.Today when I show **Samma ājiva** is also a cetasika.  It changed my  view toward cetasika.

They are not elementary mental process  which comes along with birth.

I now think that cetsikas are programmed subminds or **parallel minds**.and it can be dynamically added.**Most of the beautiful cetasikas are developed by practice of buddhism. isnt’it?**

And with little exaggeration I can say that, I can develop a modern cetasika like **samma-mobile**.
samma-mobile is the right usage of mobile.dont try to justify that right use of mobile as part of something already there in so-and-so cetasika.. just take it as example only.

With total re-programming process only dedicated to right usage of mobile. I can build a fresh submind /cetasca related to mobile usage.and then it will be mounted so effective to the level of mind moments. and evaluate each mind moment from the perspective of mobile usage.

Answer (score 0):

> So far I was under impression that cetasicas are elementary mental
> factor.

Cetasikas are mental factors. (characteristics of minds).
They don't arise alone.
They arise with mind and other cetasikas.
When they arise they arise at the same time.
When they cease they cease at the same time.
They have the same object.
They depend on the same Rupa.

> Today when I show Samma ājiva is also a cetasika. It changed my view
> toward cetasika.

There are 3 Virati-cetasikas (abstinent-cetasikas)
They are not long time existing actions as you have thought. They are momentary.
When we **abstain** from a verbal or bodily wrong doing, the "abstinent-cetasikas" arises in the mind. It is a virati-cetasika.

> And with little exaggeration I can say that, I can develop a modern
> cetasika like samma-mobile.
> No. All the cetasikas that exists were already found by the Buddha. That is why he was omniscient.
> It is considered the number 52 can not be changed.

If think of the new-cetasika you have mentioned, it should be a combined one of 2/3 virati cetasikas.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia appears to have a sufficient article on the [fifty-two mental factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_factors_(Buddhism)#Therav%C4%81da_Abhidhamma_tradition) found in the mass-market Theravada commentary called [Abhidhammattha-Sangaha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhidhammattha-sangaha). Wikipedia divides the fifty-two cetasika into:

- Seven universal mental factors
- Six occasional mental factors
- Fourteen unwholesome mental factors
- Twenty-five beautiful mental factors.

Sammā-ājīva (right livelihood) is one of the beautiful mental factors rather than is a universal mental factors. The beautiful mental factors (sobhana cetasika) accompany the wholesome consciousnesses (kusala citta).